# Чем вскрыть прошивку спутникового ресивера?

Tags: ассемблер, c++

Имеется прошивка спутникового ресивера. Хотелось бы в ней что-то изменить, но файл прошивки бинарный - bin - открывается только в Hex редакторе. Кто подскажет дальнейший вариант действий, или это все очень трудно и нужны знания ассемблера?

Comment: ассемблер - да, более того - под данный проц. а ещё она шифрованная может быть...

Answer (score 1):

Берете IDA (лучший существующий дизассемблер) и дизассемблируете.
Если она не знает ядро процессора, используемого в вашем устройстве, тогда придется искать альтернативные программы.